# Null Pointer Exception in android when switching activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I just started programming for Android when my boss asked me to make him a mobile app so I completed all of this in two days and taught myself as I was doing it, mostly from this site. I keep getting a nullPointerException when i run my program and click on the button that switches the the next activity

First activity:

```
package com.Android.HelpDeskMobileApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
public class HelpDeskFront extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);
        Button serviceButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.serviceButton),
                orderButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.OrderButton),
                programmingButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ProgrammingButton);
        serviceButton.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
        orderButton.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
        programmingButton.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
    }
    private OnClickListener buttonListener = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String serviceType = null;
            Intent i = new Intent(HelpDeskFront.this, Main.class);
            if (v.getId() == R.id.serviceButton)
                serviceType = "service";
            else if (v.getId() == R.id.OrderButton)
                serviceType = "order";
            else if (v.getId() == R.id.ProgrammingButton)
                serviceType = "programming";
            i.putExtra("serviceType", serviceType);
            startActivityForResult(i, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        };
}
```

Buttons lead to my second activity:

```
package com.Android.HelpDeskMobileApp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Main extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final Button send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendRequest);
        send.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
    }
    private OnClickListener buttonListener = new OnClickListener() {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> data = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
        final EditText caller = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CallerEnter), 
                 callExt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CallNumberEnter),
                 computerName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ComputerNameEnter),
                 location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LocationEnter),
                 request = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RequestEnter);

        public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = getIntent();
        final String serviceType = i.getStringExtra("serviceType");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, HelpDeskEnd.class);
            final String[] email = {"target emails"};
            data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Caller: ", textToString(caller)));
            data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Call Ext: ", textToString(callExt)));
            data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Computer Name: ", textToString(computerName)));
            data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Locations: ", textToString(location)));
            data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Request: ", textToString(request)));
            sendData(data);

            String body = data.get(0).toString() + " " + data.get(1).toString() + " " +
                    data.get(2).toString() + " " + data.get(3).toString() + " " + 
                    data.get(4).toString();
            Mail mail = new Mail("an email", "email password");
            mail.setTo(email);
            mail.setBody(body);
            mail.setFrom("an email");
            mail.setSubject(serviceType);
            try {
                mail.send();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                 Log.e("Send Mail", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            intent.putExtra("serivceType", serviceType);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    };
    private String textToString(EditText x)
    {
        return x.getText().toString();
    }
    private void sendData(ArrayList<NameValuePair> data)
    {
        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https//www.awebsite.com/phpfile.php");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This is probably some really easy fix. Thanks for any help. Here is my manifest file also I don't know if its helpful but here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.Android.HelpDeskMobileApp"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/logo" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".HelpDeskFront"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
                  android:name=".Main">
                  <intent-filter></intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
                  android:name=".HelpDeskEnd">
                  <intent-filter></intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

The error happens when I hit the button to go from the first activity to the .main activity. I have tried commenting out different parts of the code but I cannot figure out what is causing the Null Pointer Exception. Thanks.
log cat:

```
    07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.Android.HelpDeskMobileApp/com.Android.HelpDeskMobileApp.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1744)
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770):     at com.Android.HelpDeskMobileApp.Main$1.<init>(Main.java:35)
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770):     at com.Android.HelpDeskMobileApp.Main.<init>(Main.java:31)
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1301)
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-13 18:37:29.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you post the exception you get , switch to DDMS mode and check for error in your logcat and post your exception here

Comment: Thanks for putting the code up, show us your logcat output as well?

Comment: "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException ... at com.Android.HelpDeskMobileApp.Main.<init>(Main.java:31)" What's on line 31 of Main?

Comment: I saw that and tried to comment the receiving Intent out and still got the error but it moved to a different line. currently line 31 is: empty, line 32 is:   `Intent i = getIntent();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's line 34 in Main. The lines under "Caused by" in the logcat output are where the relevant info usually is.

Okay, culprit should be the initializers

```
Intent i = getIntent();
        final String serviceType = i.getStringExtra("serviceType");
        final EditText caller = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CallerEnter), 
            callExt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CallNumberEnter),
            computerName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ComputerNameEnter),
            location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LocationEnter),
            request = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RequestEnter);
```

occurring in the Object constructor. Since the `onClickListener` constructor will run before the `onCreate()` method, `getIntent()` will return null, and you will not have set your contentView so all your findViewById()'s will also return null.

The correct way would be:

```
private OnClickListener buttonListener = new OnClickListener() {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> data = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);

        public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = getIntent();
        final String serviceType = i.getStringExtra("serviceType");
        final EditText caller = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CallerEnter), 
            callExt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CallNumberEnter),
            computerName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ComputerNameEnter),
            location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LocationEnter),
            request = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RequestEnter);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, HelpDeskEnd.class);
            final String[] email = {"target emails"};
            data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Caller: ", textToString(caller)));
            data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Call Ext: ", textToString(callExt)));
            data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Computer Name: ", textToString(computerName)));
            data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Locations: ", textToString(location)));
            data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Request: ", textToString(request)));
            sendData(data);

            String body = data.get(0).toString() + " " + data.get(1).toString() + " " +
                    data.get(2).toString() + " " + data.get(3).toString() + " " + 
                    data.get(4).toString();
            Mail mail = new Mail("an email", "email password");
            mail.setTo(email);
            mail.setBody(body);
            mail.setFrom("an email");
            mail.setSubject(serviceType);
            try {
                mail.send();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                 Log.e("Send Mail", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            intent.putExtra("serivceType", serviceType);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    };
```

Comment: That is what i thought, line 34 is: `final String serviceType = i.getStringExtra("serviceType");` If i comment this out and just add a serviceType variable down in the onClickListener and set it to null i still get the same error but with line 36 which is: `final EditText caller = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CallerEnter)` Is there something wrong with my R.java file or something?

Comment: i is null because the `getIntent()` will return null since the `onClickListener` is instantiated before `onCreate()`. Put the `getIntent()` and dependent variable instantiations in the `onClick()`

Comment: All of the findViewById()'s also need to be moved into the onclick. They will not work where they are. `onCreate()` will not have been called so you have not added your contentView.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help Finally got it to work and learned some more about how this onCreate() works.

Answer (score 0):

Does `HelpDeskFront.startActivity(intent);` solve the problem?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean here? `i.putExtra("serviceType", serviceType);
      startActivity(i);` That just gives me an error. doesnt let the porgram run

Answer (score 0):

private OnClickListener buttonListener = new OnClickListener() {

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String serviceType = null;
        Intent i = new Intent(HelpDeskFront.this, Main.class);
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.serviceButton :
            serviceType = "service";
            break;
        case R.id.OrderButton :
            serviceType = "order";
            break;
        case R.id.ProgrammingButton :
            serviceType = "programming";
            break;
        }
        i.putExtra("serviceType", serviceType);
        startActivity(i);// change this to startActivityForResult(yourintent,Intent.FILL_IN_DATA)
    }
};
```

Just a thought at first glance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use if(view==programmingButton)else if(view==another button) like this instead of switch,can you post the logcat and tell which code(as part of onclick listener or second activity) to null pointer exception...

Answer (score 0):

The error is on line 34

```
final String serviceType = i.getStringExtra("serviceType");
```

which means that "i" is probably not initialized properly.

I would try this so that the contexts are right.

```
Intent i = Main.this.getIntent();
```

Or you could just create a new intent like you did in the other activity.

Comment: This fixed the NullPointerException that i was getting on line 34 so thanks! Now im getting a different error when doing same thing. Will post LogCat and edit the code changes i made

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of issues with how your app is even starting off in its main activity!

You need to set the listeners in the onStart() method not in the onCreate() method. onCreate() isn't always called every time the activity is shown.

You don't need to find out what button has been clicked using a switch, if/else, or anything so complex... each button has its own onClickListener(). In the listener call a private method to start the new activity.

Pass whatever data you want through the intent using putExtra().

Here is an example...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate( final Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        this.setContentView( R.layout.main );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        final Button _serviceButton = (Button)this.findViewById( R.id.buttonService );
        final Button _orderButton = (Button)this.findViewById( R.id.buttonOrder );
        final Button _progButton = (Button)this.findViewById( R.id.buttonProgramming );

        _serviceButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick( final View v ) {
                MainActivity.this.doSomeButtonClick( "service" );
            }
        } );

        _orderButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick( final View v ) {
                MainActivity.this.doSomeButtonClick( "order" );
            }
        } );

        _progButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick( final View v ) {
                MainActivity.this.doSomeButtonClick( "programming" );
            }
        } );
    }

    private void doSomeButtonClick( final String type ) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this, Activity1.class );
        intent.putExtra( "serviceType", type );
        this.startActivity( intent );
    }
}
```

Comment: See i didn't even know that the OnStart() method existed. I followed one short tutorial on making some text appear on the screen and dove right into this app. Thanks so much; I just learned a lot. I guess spending a year learning java does not an android developer make

Comment: You add @Override decelerations before a lot of your methods. When i do this i always get errors. Are they that important or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: HAHA Yeah the whole "Android way" is interesting! I didn't look but I briefly noted you are making an HTTP request. I will STRONGLY suggest, if you are not already doing so, use an AsyncTask and run your request on a separate thread.

Comment: The @Override are the overridden methods of the Activity class. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

Comment: btw- I'm saying all of this, especially about how you've written your intents and what-not, because your current error is only the tip of the iceburg! You are going to have a couple of more errors including an ANR when you make your HTTP connection after "correcting" the immediate NullPointerException.

Comment: thanks again, ill look at the AsyncTask. I pretty much copy pasted the HTTP request stuff from another question so maybe it will work. thanks